# Changes in background agents (GDR3)

Tags: update, background-tasks, gdr-3

I'm working on an app which sets the lockscreen, and I'm struggling to keep my `Background Agent` under the 10MB hard limit (and it's really hard to do this if it uses 5MB on the very first line of your code..).

Yesterday I downloaded the updated emulator images, with the GDR3 ones, and I found out that they changed the memory limitation for background agents, but I can't find anything online to confirm this.

I've already read about the background audio agents, but I'm talking of the plain `Periodic Task`.

Since `Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit` returns `20MB`, it seems that we have double memory this time, and that's why my agent works fine on the GDR3 emulator while it crashes on my phone (and I'm using the same screen's size so it's not about lw memory devices and stuff).

What I need to know is if there's something official on this matter, because I don't want to keep on developing the app as if I have 20MB and then find out that I've got just the half of them.

So here's the question: can I rely on this information or we still have just 10 MB available for our `Periodic Tasks` ?

Comment: Sorry but this Q&A is not for development questions.

Comment: Actually the question was more like "hey, does anyone know if GDR3 brings some changes in the way WP manages the background agents?". I've added the details to post a more complete question :)

Comment: Sure. But you wrote it in a very "dev" way. I think this kind of question (with so specific background on it) will be more easily answered on Stackoverflow. Don't think this like a banish, just imagine that if someone try to find something related of changes in background agents to implement something different they will probably try Stackoverflow. I think your question is good to stackoverflow but here it needs to be "cropped" to remove some "dev" background to understand. What you think?

Comment: I agree with @VitorCanova, but to quickly answer the question the limit was raised with GDR3 but only for devices with more memory (like the 1520). Older devices will have the limits they've always had. I don't have a resource to hand but this is what I recall from when I worked at Nokia. Either way, there will always be some people who don't update and your apps should still work for them.